# MySQL - Get values from previous rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to reconstruct data that has a tree structure.

Example - Country / City:

```
1) USA
1.1) New York
1.2) Chicago 
2) France
2.1) Paris
2.2) Lyon 
3) China
```

In my database it looks like this:

```
|  Element | Level | Row |
|:--------:|:-----:|:---:|
|    USA   |   1   |  1  |
| New York |   2   |  2  |
|  Chicago |   2   |  3  |
|  France  |   1   |  4  |
|   Paris  |   2   |  5  |
|   Lyon   |   2   |  6  |
|   China  |   1   |  7  |
```

Based on the sequence (row) of my entries I can reconstruct the tree structure. For each row I look for the nearest previous row that has Level-1.

max(pre.Row)   /   pre.Row < cur.Row   /   pre.Level = cur.Level-1

Following code is working and it returns the right results. My problem is that the table is 7 million rows large and therefore it takes a lot of time. It is like comparing 7 million times 7 million rows...

```
SELECT cur.`Row`, (
    SELECT max(pre.`Row`)
    FROM `abc`.`def` AS pre
    WHERE pre.`Row` < cur.`Row` 
    AND pre.`Level`=cur.`Level`-1
) AS prev_row
FROM `abc`.`def` AS cur
;
```

Is there a faster way to implement this?

Maybe with loops or user variables? I could imagine that you actually start from the current row and then test if the previous row meets the conditions otherwise look for the next previous row and so on. This will reduce the opertions to 7 million times ~5. I never worked with loops so I have no clue if this is possible in SQL. Any ideas?

Comment: is there data with other level values other than 2 and 1?

Comment: Do you have an index on (Level, Row)?

Comment: @Tin Tran: Yes, there are more than 2 levels. It can go up to 20.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel: Yes, I set an index on Row as well as on Level

Comment: you can try my answer after adding in 17 more levels and see if it's faster than using max() like yours... i would think it would be faster since it only has to sort once but you never know for sure till you try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my try with 3 levels you can add levels if you have more, not sure why it's returning weird values that look like encoded values but CAST() AS unSIGNED gets you prev_row just as your query.

```
SELECT Row,
       CAST(ELT(level-1,@level_1,@level_2,@level_3) as UNSIGNED) as prev_row,
       @level_1 := IF(`level` = 1, row, @level_1),
       @level_2 := IF(`level` = 2, row, @level_2),
       @level_3 := IF(`level` = 3, row, @level_3)
FROM `def`
ORDER BY Row ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/719b2/22

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. I will adjust the code, try it out and then you get my feedback

Comment: I modified the code to my needs and it work perfectly as far as I observed. It took only two minutes to execute!
My own code has been running for more than 8h when I killed the process...
Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. 2 minutes seems like a long time too, i guess i never played with that much data.